# Running programs as sudo doesn't work

Tags: command-line, 18.04, sudo

Installing tools and other using command line in Ubuntu 18.04 with sudo works perfectly.
example: `sudo apt install ...` works perfectly.
Running tools and programs via the command line as sudo doesn't work at all.
Running the same programs and tools as normal user works perfectly.
Example: `start gtkwave` as normal user makes the gtkwave GUI pop up.
        Start gtkwave as sudo, asks for password and then ends in:
        `sudo: gtkwave: command not found`.

I must say that some tools invoked on the command line as sudo work flawlessly, for example I can start Atom from the command line as a normal user and as sudo.

Is this maybe because the tools/programs not running as sudo are not installed in the common Linux folders like `/bin` or `/usr/bin` but as programs under `/opt` (these are added to the path and have necessary environments set)?

Does anybody have any idea why this happens?

Comment: can you do an echo $PATH with and without sudo and check if the path has the library needed to run the program?

Comment: If gtkwave works normal user then why are you trying to run it as root user? Again was it designed to work with sudo?

Comment: @blvdeer I'm having the same problem with OP. I tried the two commands and the outputs are the same. Actually I can't even run vi with root account, but I have to install with a root account.

Answer (score 7):

By default, `sudo` searches for programs using its own `secure_path` that is defined in the `/etc/sudoers` file. From `man sudoers`:

> ```
>  secure_path   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't
>                trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environ‐
>                ment variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if
>                you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user
>                path”.  Users in the group specified by the exempt_group
>                option are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not
>                set by default.
> ```

Note that in spite of the last line there, the default Ubuntu `/etc/sudoers` **does** set it:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

so neither the invoking user's `PATH` nor root's `PATH` will effect whether programs are located when using `sudo`.

If you really want programs in locations such as `/opt` to be executable via `sudo`, you will need to either

- use the full path e.g. `sudo /opt/somepath/bin/prog`
- modify the sudoers `secure_path` to include the locations - if you decide to do this, please use `sudo visudo` to catch any syntax errors (else you risk locking yourself out of `sudo` altogether).

However, you should probably read [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) before proceeding.

Comment: Or you could add yourself to the `exempt_group`as it states in the man_page excerpt that you posted (or set exempt_group to your user group id a.k.a. user id.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running

`sudo myCommand`

you can either do

`sudo /full/path/to/myCommand`

or

`sudo "$(which myCommand)"`